# MVC .NET | Check Another Field In The Login Process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity

I have a MVC 5 project (.NET) and I added another field to my User object(and also to the DB in 'AspNetUsers' table) in identity (using this article http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html).

The field called "Active" and its purpose is to allow admins to freeze accounts (temporarily).

Whats lead me to my question:

How can I check that field for each user in the login process ? so if the field is set to '0' I denied the login and if the field is set to '1' I allow the login.

I tried to do it in a separate query to database and its take forever(to do two queries for the login), killing my web app, I have to do the login and check that field in one query to the database.

How can I do it ? Thank you.

Comment: A call to the database takes forever? Are you bringing the entire Users collection into memory and then filtering? A call like that should be pretty much instant.

Comment: @mattytommo My DB is SQL Server On Azure, its take time.

Comment: @Ron - why are you doing this?  Identity already has two fields for Lockout, LockoutEnabled and LockoutEndDateUtc.  Use UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id) to determine if the user is locked out.  Of, for whatever reason that doesn't work for you, why not simply implement a ValidUser claim, and assign this to all users, and remove it from users you want to lock out?  Then deny access to anyone that's not a ValidUser

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I tried it long time ago and i wasnt satisfed from it.
But after you mention it, i gave it another try and its works fine, i use your solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find your user information after successful login and check your flag. 
For example, the following part of Login method of AccountController may look like:

```
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user.IsLocked)
                return View("Lockout");
            else
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

Comment: Pavel its also two query to the DB, no ?
One :await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
Two : await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is two queries. But you may try to use build-in "lockout" feature. Check appropriate methods in UserManager.

Answer (score 0):

Running two queries shouldn't be significantly slow so you might want to look into that. However here's how you can perform the check using the existing Identity structure

Override the User entity if you haven't already and add your new property. Make sure the Usermanager is using ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public bool Frozen { get;set;}
}
```

Then override the SignInManager's PasswordSignInAsync Method

```
public override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
{

    //Do your custom login here

}
```

I'd recommend decompiling Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DLL to see exactly what the sign in manager is doing. From recollection it Finds a user, checks they arent locked out, checks the password, checks if two factor auth is needed and then signs the user in.